# How to change only one element of a class without giving it an ID?

Tags: html, css

**My question:**

Is it possibile to ONLY change one element of a class without *(a) giving it an own ID* and (b) *without doing inline-style* in the HTML document?

**Why do I want to do that?**

I am using a software where the program creates classes and ids by itself (for a questionnaire). I cannot change or add classes/ids nor can I change the html. The only thing I can do is grab those already defined classes with CSS and style them (which is what I want to do).

**Example:**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyGWc/

In this example I only want to change the background-color of the second ".class2" to green (whereas the first ".class2" div should remain red).

```
<div class="class0">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            This div has a red background color. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="class0">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2"> 
            This div should be green without adding an ID to it. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.class1 {
    height: 3em;
}

.class2 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried to use :nth-child(2) and :nth-of-type(2) but as far as I've understood it, it only selects the target child under a parent element? In my example the div elements with the class ".class2" are not siblings. So those won't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: your HTML code may make the actual problem unclear, the question is ***is the `class2` always nested inside `class1` and `class1` is nested inside `class0`?***

Comment: How many div with class '.class2' in your page and for which div's you want to set background-color:green?

Comment: @King King: Exactly: .class2 is always nested inside .class1. And .class1 is always inside .class0. But you're right, my example is making it a little bit more complicated (since I don't need .class0)

Comment: @malkam: there are two divs with the ".class2". I want to change the SECOND .class2 div only (without giving it an ID because I can't in the program I use to create the questionnaire).

Comment: if so you have a solution which has been given by Rupam Datta, it's the only way (of course also a very beautiful way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you rightly said, since the class2 elements are not siblings, you cannot use nth-child. So the solution to your problem is using nth-child for class0. Here is the code

```
.class0:nth-child(2) .class2{
    background-color: green;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nyGWc/3/)

Comment: Nice! I'd have done the same. If you care about IE8 support you'll need a polyfill, [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) works nicely.

Comment: @JackWilliams This is fantastic to have for MSIEs.

Answer (score 2):

Select the second class0, then select its child class2. Using `nth-of-type` allows the `.class0` elements to not need to be under the same parent element.

```
.class0:nth-of-type(2) .class2 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyGWc/2/)